# OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter annotation config

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, filter, annotations

In order to overcome LazyInitializationException I've decided to use OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter but I couldn't do it annotation style. I've tried set it up two ways:

First in onStartup method from WebApplicationInitializer:

```
OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter entityManagerInViewFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        entityManagerInViewFilter.setEntityManagerFactoryBeanName("entityManagerFactory");
        entityManagerInViewFilter.setPersistenceUnitName("defaultPersistenceUnit");
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = sc.addFilter("openEntityManagerInViewFilter", entityManagerInViewFilter);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

Second by creating new class that extends OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and has annotation @WebFilter:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class MainFilter extends OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter {

    public MainFilter() {
        setEntityManagerFactoryBeanName("entityManagerFactory");
        setPersistenceUnitName("defaultPersistanceUnit");
    }

}
```

Each time I got "No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined" or "No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined". My entity manager factory is defined in @Configuration class.

How can I configure this filter without web.xml file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the boot process can be pretty unclear (which can lead to wrong configurations), I decided to give a detailed answer, but also a "too long; didn't read" for those who want to jump to the answer immediately.

## TL;DR

The easiest way is one of these two options:

**Option 1: [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html)**

This is closer to Spring than [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) and thus may be easier to configure when you also need to configure it with other beans.

Use something like this for your web configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackages")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor interceptor = new OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor();
        interceptor.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

The important part the addInterceptors(), in which the interceptor is created and added to Spring Web.

And to point Spring Web to config class, you need something like this:

```
public class MyServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MainConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

MyServletInitializer will be automatically detected by Spring, because it's a subclass of [AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html), which is an implementation of [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html). And Spring Web will automatically be detected by the Servlet container, because Spring Web contains a service provider implementation of [ServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) by default, which gets detected automatically. This implementation is called [SpringServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html).

**Option 2: [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html)**
If you don't want to use the interceptor, you can use the filter.
The filter has a wider range scope in which an entityManager can be shared per HTTP request, but interceptors are closer to Spring, making it easier to wire beans with it (in case needed).

```
public class MyServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MainConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()};
    }
}
```

**Additional notes:**

- Make sure that you have correct names of entityManagerFactoryBean. See documentation of [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html), or my detailed description below.
- Make sure that configurations aren't imported multiple times, otherwise you can get hard to debug problems. For more info, see my detailed description below.

---

## Why/when to use OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

[OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) is an implementation of the [OSIV pattern](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) (Open Session In View) for JPA. (A [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) is the native Hibernate version of an [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html). So for JPA it can be called: Open EntityManager In View pattern.) In this pattern, a single EntityManager is shared/reused within a single HTTP request, and closed when the HTTP request finishes.

The benefits of using the OSIV pattern are:

- better database performance compared to when a single HTTP request causes multiple different transactions and entitymangers to be opened
- allows JPA to use 1st level caching
- easier programming, you don't have to worry about [LazyInitializationExceptions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html), which can be caused when the entityManager is closed and you access methods on entities that require a persistent context
- it may be required when you're using custom Spring security filters that use JPA.

But it may also cause the persistent context to be opened longer than needed, which may harm performance.
Some also consider the OSIV pattern as an anti-pattern: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/ This web page also discusses other solutions to avoid both LazyInitializationExceptions and the OSIV pattern.

## Servlet 3.0 and configuration options

Since Servlet 3.0, the servlet specification supports pluggability, it allows you to switch from web.xml to programmatic configurations and annotation configurations. Although annotation configurations don't support all features that web.xml and programmatic configurations do, such as ordering of servlets and filters. When using annotations only, it can be cumbersome if you have to extend and existing filters just to be able to configure it, as you do here:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class MainFilter extends OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
```

An easy way to configure the web app in Spring is to use a programmatic configuration. When a Servlet >= 3.0 container starts (such as Tomcat >= 7), it will search for web.xml and for a [ServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) service provider implementations (which also requires you to define a file in META-INF/services). The ServletContainerInitializer implementation allows the servlet container to be configured programmatically.

## Connecting Spring to the Servlet container

Spring Web by default contains an implemenation of ServletContainerInitializer, called [SpringServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html), so that you don't have to create an implementation of ServletContainerInitializer yourself. This makes it easier for framework designer to configure their framework to work with the container.
To make use of this, you have to create an implementation of Springs [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) interface. This implementation is automatically discoverd by Spring (SpringServletContainerInitializer). It provides you a [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) instance, which allows you to configure the container (servlets and filters) programmatically.
An easier way is to create a subclass of [AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) (which is an implementation of WebApplicationInitializer), so that you don't have to configure everything directly using the ServletContext.

## How to achieve OSIV

Multiple ways to achieve OSIV. The best option may differ per project.

In OSIV, you want the EntityManager to the opened/started at the beginning of the HTTP request and to be closed when the corresponding HTTP response ends. Demarcation is the proccess of opening and closing the entityManager and transaction. Depending on what type of web application or framework you are using, you can shift a bit in the exact location of demarcation.

Some demarcation options:

### Option 1 - bypass Spring, annotations-only, OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter (not recommended)

You can bypass Spring by letting the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter be directly detected by the servletContainer, or by subclassing it and annotating it, or by specifying it in web.xml.

This is similar to your approach:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class MainFilter extends OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
```

This approach is not recommended because it's a bit cumbersome.

### Option 2 - manually programmatically via WebApplicationInitializer, OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

In this approach you create an implemenatation of Springs [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) to get hold of the [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

Then you can create and configure the openEntityManagerInViewFilter manually:

```
OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter filter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = registerServletFilter(servletContext, filter);
registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE), true, "/*");
```

Note you'll also have to create the Spring ApplicationContext and DispatcherServlet yourself. See the documentation of [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) for an example.

### Option 3 - programmatically via AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter (recommended)

This is the main approach to enable OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in a Spring application.

As described earlier, the servlet container will automatically detect Springs [SpringServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html), and then Spring will automatically detect our MyServletInitializer (see below) because its superclass ([AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html)) is an implementation of [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html).

From MyServletInitializer, Spring will load your core application config, the rootConfigClasses, in which you can define your JPA beans.

Example:

```
public class MyServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MainConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()};
    }
}
```

Spring main config file example:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MainConfig {
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB10Dialect");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("url", "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/myDatabase");
        properties.put("user", "root");
        properties.put("password", "myPassword");

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        config.setDataSourceProperties(properties);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTxManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTxManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return jpaTxManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
        HibernateJpaDialect jpaDialect = new HibernateJpaDialect();
        emf.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
        emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        emf.setPackagesToScan("mypackage");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return emf;
    }
}
```

Spring web config example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackages")
public class WebConfig {}
```

### Option 4: no filter, @Transactional on Spring controller methods

If your application doesn't require filters, and your template layer is rendered from within a Spring controller, than you can demarcate the controller method with @Transactional instead of using pure OSIV.

In this case, make sure `@EnableTransactionManagement` is set on the Spring configuration and the controller method is annotated with `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Note that this doesn't work when you are for example using JSP or other common templates, because then the text isn't generated in the controller method. Instead, a model and view object is created, which is then forwarded to the template for rendering, but once the controller method is finished, the entityManager is closed before the rendering, which can cause the LazyInitializationException when you access lazy loaded entity properties.

### Option 5 - OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor instead of a filter (recommended)

Whereas filters are part of the servlet api, [webRequestInterceptors](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequestInterceptor.html) are part of Spring Web and thus a bit closer to Spring.
One of these webRequestInterceptors is [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html), which is the interceptor version of OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.

The documentation says: "*In contrast to OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter, this interceptor is set up in a Spring application context and can thus take advantage of bean wiring.*"

So where the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter is initialized in a WebApplicationInitializer (such as AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer), OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor can be initialized in a Spring configuration class.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackages")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor interceptor = new OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor();
        interceptor.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

Note that the interceptor is in a deeper layer than the filter. If you have filters that need to use an entityManager, than the interceptors cannot provide it, but the other way around should work.

### Usage info about OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

As described in the documentation of [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html), you have to make sure that a Spring bean exist under the right name, otherwise OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter may give the error that you describe: "*No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined*".
From the documentation:

> Looks up the EntityManagerFactory in Spring's root web application
>   context. Supports an "entityManagerFactoryBeanName" filter init-param
>   in web.xml; the default bean name is "entityManagerFactory". As an
>   alternative, the "persistenceUnitName" init-param allows for retrieval
>   by logical unit name (as specified in persistence.xml).

In your question, you didn't show how you did define the EntityManagerFactory exactly.

## How to test whether it is working

Even when you don't get a LazyInitializationException, it doesn't mean that entitymanager is shared.

To verify whether it is working correctly, you can put org.springframework at DEBUG logging level in your logging framework.

When testing, preferably use a tool like Wget or Curl instead of a webbrowser, because a webbrowser may trigger multiple HTTP requests (such as favicon.ico), which makes the logs less clear.

When a HTTP requests triggers entityManager requests in multiple repositories, all should use the same EntityManager, so for a single HTTP request, you should only see a single line with something like:

```
21:48:46.872 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
```

and a single:

```
21:48:46.878 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

And when you have multiple entityManager requests in multiple repositories, you should see that they are using the same thread-bound entityManager. So you should see multiple lines with:

```
21:48:46.876 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1847515591<open>)] for JPA transaction
```

## Problems while configuring

I had a difficult to debug problem when trying to disable web.xml to something like web.xml.old, because IntelliJ somehow made a mapping in the IntelliJ project configuration to the renamed web.xml.old, causing it to still use the xml configuration.

Another problem can be when your Spring configurations are somehow imported multiple times, for example if you use @import in the webConfiguration to import the mainConfiguration and you specify them both in your AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, then things may be imported multiple times, causing hard to debug problems. 
If your configuration is unclear because you have many, you may want to create a constructor with a simple println message so verify that it's only created once.

Answer (score -1):

WebApplicationInitializer is a fine general-purpose way of registering servlets, filters,and listeners in Java when deploying to a Servlet 3.0 container. But if you’re registering a filter and only need to map that filter to DispatcherServlet, then there’s a
shortcut in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.
 To register one or more filters and map them to DispatcherServlet, all you need
to do is override the getServletFilters() method of AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.
For example, the following getServletFilters()
method overrides the one from AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
to register a filter:

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { new MyFilter() };
}
```

Here is my snippet of WebAppInitializer code

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            System.out.println("*****加载MySqlConfig*******");
            return new Class<?>[] { MySqlConfig.class };
        }

        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            System.out.println("*****加载WebConfig*******");
            return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
        }

        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            System.out.println("*****要拦截的请求*******");
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }
        //Register your filter here
        protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
            System.out.println("*********加载filter**********");
            return new Filter[]{new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()};
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please also try to explain your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.